# How to get a (chat-like) server to accept a "type" object from the client?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, idioms

How can adjust `WorkerRunnable` to accept a `QueryType`, and, based on that object, send objects for the corresponding query to the client?  Currently one object is sent from the queue to the client, then, when the client sends back the object, the database is updated accordingly.

It should probably be called `MetaConnection`, actually.  It might contain login credentials for basic security, an SQL query, a queue type, or, really, anything.

Right now there's just the one queue, but I would like to add other queues and functionality.

`QueryType`:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.jdbc;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class QueryType implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QueryType.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
    private final Queues query = Queues.FOO;

    public QueryType() {
    }

    public Queues getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

}
```

`WorkerRunnable`:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.server.streams;

import net.bounceme.dur.jdbc.Title;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.jdbc.Queries;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WorkerRunnable.class.getName());
    protected Socket socket = null;
    private RecordsQueueWrapper recordsQueue = null;
    private final Queries queries = new Queries();

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, RecordsQueueWrapper recordsQueue) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
        this.recordsQueue = recordsQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Title serverTitle = null;
        Title clientTitle = null;
        boolean queueEmpty = false;
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
            do {
                try {
                    serverTitle = recordsQueue.pop();
                    log.info(serverTitle.toString());
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(serverTitle);
                    log.fine(serverTitle.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    clientTitle = (Title) objectInputStream.readObject();
                    queries.updateTitle(clientTitle);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
                    queueEmpty = true;
                }
            } while (!queueEmpty);
        } catch (java.io.EOFException eofe) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "why is there no record from client?\n", eofe);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WorkerRunnable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```